# how to cast one name of object to object (combobox)

Tags: .net, vb.net

i have name of many combobox in string variable (vb.net )
how to cast name of object to object

like "combobox1"(string) convert to ComboBox1(object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Controls.Find()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?view=netframework-4.8) to do a **recursive** search of the form.  This will find the control even if it is nested inside other container controls, like a Panel or GroupBox:

```
Dim ctlName As String = "combobox1"
Dim cb As ComboBox = Me.Controls.Find(ctlName, True).FirstOrDefault
If Not IsNothing(cb) Then
    ' ... do someting with "cb" ...
End If
```

The Find() function returns an **array** of matches, thus the need for `FirstOrDefault`.

If you want slightly more robust code, then do it in more explicit steps:

```
Dim ctlName As String = "combobox1"
Dim ctl As Control = Me.Controls.Find(ctlName, True).FirstOrDefault
If Not IsNothing(ctl) AndAlso TypeOf ctl Is ComboBox Then
    Dim cb As ComboBox = DirectCast(ctl, ComboBox)
    ' ... do someting with "cb" ...
End If
```

Comment: I get an Option Strict warning from the first set of code. Can't convert Control to ComboBox

Comment: @mary Then use the second version.

Comment: I just thought you might want to correct your code.

Comment: @Mary Technically there is nothing wrong with it.   It is a **warning** after all, not a compile error.  If you don't have Option Strict on, then you won't see that message.  Just depends on your project and your comfort level in knowing what it is doing.

Comment: Actually, it fails to compile with Option Strict on. I guess you are comfortable with Option Strict off.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming all of the strings you have reference `ComboBox`es on the current form, you can do this:

```
Dim myString As String = "combobox1"
Dim myComboBox As ComboBox

myComboBox = Controls(myString) ' Replace myString with your string
```

Note that this will throw an exception if `Controls(myString)` does not return a `ComboBox`.

If you are not certain whether the returned control will be a `ComboBox`, combine the above with `TryCast` and handle the `Nothing` result if it fails:

```
myComboBox = TryCast(Controls(myString), ComboBox) ' Replace myString with your string
If myComboBox Is Not Nothing Then
    ' Your code
End If
```

Comment: very tanks

but after run this code (I'm sure have combobox401 in form ) 

        Dim myString As String = "ComboBox401"
        Dim myComboBox As ComboBox
        myComboBox = TryCast(Controls(myString), ComboBox)

breakpoint : 
myComboBox Still nothing !!!!!!

Comment: If `myComboBox` is `Nothing` then `ComboBox401` does not exist in the `Controls` collection for the current form, or is not a `ComboBox`...

Comment: Your code assumes the ComboBox is not in a panel or other container.

Comment: @LarsTech You're right.  The first few words of my answer: _Presuming all of the strings you have reference ComboBoxes on the current form_

Comment: thats right my control into panel. tanks LarsTech , tanks martin.